# How to set value of model property in the View from the ViewBag?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to set the value of a hidden property using the `ViewBag` in MVC3. Here is what I have come up with:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PROCESS_ID, new { @value = ViewBag.processID })
```

In the controller I set the `ViewBag.processID` to a `long`. In the View, I simply want to assign the value of that to the Process_ID of the strongly typed model. However, through the ViewBag property gets set correctly, it does not pass into the value of the hidden attribute.

**Generated HTML:**

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PROCESS_ID must be a number." id="PROCESS_ID" name="PROCESS_ID" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Am I missing something? This seems simple enough. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you already know in the controller what the process_id value is, why both sending it to the client at all?

Comment: A lot of my validation is done Client side and some of it is based on this field.

Comment: Then why not set it in the model before you send the model to the view?

Comment: ... that makes complete sense. That is a much better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just do this

```
@{ Model.PROCESS_ID = ViewBag.PROCESS_ID; }
```